# Understanding async methods, does this example eat up CPU time?

Tags: c#

I am trying to better understand the `async`-`await` pattern. To do so I have created the function below

```
private async void SayHello()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        Console.Out.WriteLine("Hello");
    }
}
```

When ran this function prints "Hello" to the console 100 times obviously. If I understand it correctly though, it would not "eat" CPU time by being stuck in the loop for some time. Once the execution gets to the `async` keyword control is passed back to the caller and continues from there. The approximately 1 seconds later control is regained and the print happens. **Is this the correct understanding?**

How is control regained after the `await` statement, whatever it may be, is completed?

Further, somewhat apart from this example say the `await` statement returned some value. How would I make sure this has completed in the control area from which `SayHello` was called?

```
SayHello();
.. Do something
// Make sure the await in SayHello has returned
```

**EDIT:**

If I have a `Form` with an `OnLoad` event handler that calls `SayHello` along with a `Button` that when clicked prints "What's up" to the output. Why does the `Form` not freeze up for 100 seconds upon loading. It seems as if control is passed back to the caller of `SayHello` when the `await` is encountered.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SayHello();
    }

    private async void SayHello()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            await Task.Delay(1000);
            Console.Out.WriteLine("Hello");
        }
    }

    private void bWhatUp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.Out.WriteLine("What's up!?");
    }
}
```

Comment: [You should not do `async void`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx), you should be returning `async Task` instead, the only place it would be acceptable to do would be `private async void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)` because `Form1_Load` is a event handler and you are not allowed to change it's return signature.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> If I have a Form with an OnLoad event handler that calls SayHello along with a Button that when clicked prints "What's up" to the output.

Good scenario. Let's consider this one; note that how things work in your original console scenario are slightly different.  I'll make some oversimplifications as I go, but you'll get the basic idea of how it works.

> Why does the Form not freeze up for 100 seconds upon loading.

Magic.

No, not really.

> It seems as if control is passed back to the caller of SayHello when the await is encountered.

Correct. So let's talk about what is really happening.

Event handlers aren't magic.  Someone called that code when the event happened. How did that work?

At the bottom of the call stack there is a loop that you cannot see. That loop is the simplest possible code you can imagine. It fetches a message out of a queue, and then executes code based on the contents of the message. Let's call this the "message loop", for obvious reasons.

The message loop starts by processing a "the program loaded a form" message, so the form load handler runs.  What does it do?  It calls SayHello.  What does SayHello do?

It creates an object that has a field called "i", sets it to zero, enters the loop, calls Task.Delay, gets a task back.

It creates a delegate with that magic object as its receiver; that delegate when invoked will resume execution of the method at the writeline at the bottom of the loop.  Call this the "continuation" of the task, because it is what happens next.

The delegate is passed to the task as its continuation, and SayHello returns.

The form loader returns.

Now the message loop is running again.  Suppose you click a button.  A button click message is queued up, eventually the message processor gets to it in the queue, and the click handler is run. It returns.

Suppose the delay time has elapsed. How the delay works, who knows, who cares, that it its business. Somehow, when the delay time is elapsed, the delay code puts a message in the message queue saying "hey, a task has completed, please call its continuation".

Eventually the message queue gets around to it, and the continuation is called. What does the continuation do?  It prints, sets the "i" field to 1, checks the loop condition, calls Task.Delay, creates a continuation for *that* task, and hey, we're doing it all again.  Except that this time when the await is hit, control is returned **to the message loop directly**.  The form loader is long gone.

Now does the magic seem a bit less magical?  The magic is simply that (1) there is a loop coordinating who gets to run next by means of a work queue, and (2) the compiler sees the "await" and turns the whole method into a special delegate on a special object that has all kinds of crazy abilities, like the ability to resume execution in the middle of a method.  (Try to guess how that works; suppose you had to write code to do that yourself; how might you do it?)

Now you might ask: how is it that the *message loop* does not peg the CPU to 100%, if any time everything else is idle, it's sitting there in a tight loop fetching messages and dispatching them. See if you can figure out how that works.

Finally: console apps do not have a message loop sitting at the bottom, like forms apps do.  Can you deduce how the console app might schedule continuations, lacking a message loop?

Comment: "At the top of the call stack". I feel like this is not the first time I've read you refer to the stack upside-down. (Unless I'm misreading this which is possible.) The message loop is at the bottom (origin?) of the stack. The top of the stack is the current location. I read that they *can* be represented sideways or upside down, but I don't know why anyone would do that. Even if there were a situation in which to refer to them upside-down I would think the standard way would be better in general.

Comment: @Sahuagin: It's probably because I have ingrained in me from years of reading x86 assembly in the debugger that stacks grow from high memory addresses to low memory addresses. You are right that *logically* I mean the bottom of the stack.